# Adding Rightclick for the rows or column and adding copy option in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add righclick and in that rightclick option to clipboard option in QT c++ ? How can we do it?

My existing code is

```
 void OTPWindow::initLogTable()
 {

      QList<OtpLog> logs;
      int ret = otpRepo.fetchOtpLogs(logs);
      if( ret != errorCodes::SUCCESS )
       {
        QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Critical, QString("OTP"),
                           QString("OTPLogs could not be fetched"),QMessageBox::Ok, this);
        msgBox.exec();
        QLOG_ERROR() << "fetchLogs error " << ret;
        return;
     }

     QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0,5,this); //5 columns
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Date")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Customer")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Server")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(QString("Author")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, new QStandardItem(QString("Description")));

     for(QList<OtpLog>::Iterator lIt = logs.begin(); lIt != logs.end(); lIt++)
    {
        OtpLog& log = *lIt;
        QList<QStandardItem*> row;
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(log.when.toString("dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm")));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.customer)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.server)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.author)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.reason)));

        model->appendRow(row);
     }

    // set the data model
    ui->tblLog->setModel(model);

   // set the column widths
   int tw = ui->tblLog->width() - 5;
   int w = tw / 6;

   for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
   {
       ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(i,w);
       tw -= w;
   }
   ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(4,tw);

 }
```

Can anyone help how to add righclick and option to the rightclick which is copy?

Comment: tblLog is QTableWidget or QTableView?

Comment: You could better explain what you want.

Comment: I want a rightclick option with copy command on each rows here?

Comment: You want to right click on a row and copy the data in the clipboard or you want to add the option to copy column to the menu that can be created by right click?

Comment: I want  right click on a row and copy the data in the clipboard

Answer (score 4):

You could add a custom context menu by setting the setContextMenuPolicy as Qt::CustomContextMenu and connecting the widget to a custom slot.

Step 1: Set the context menu policy

```
tblLog->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

Step 2: Slot function for context menu

```
public slots:
void customMenuRequested(QPoint pos);
```

and the function definition,

```
void MyWidget::customMenuRequested(QPoint pos){
    QModelIndex index=table->indexAt(pos);
    QMenu *menu=new QMenu(this);
    QAction *action1 = new QAction("Action 1", menu);
    menu->addAction(action1);
    menu->popup(tblLog->viewport()->mapToGlobal(
    QObject::connect(action1, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(MenuAction1(bool)));
    }
```

Step 3: connect customContextMenuRequested from tbllog to your slot function

```
QObject::connect(tbllog, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),
    SLOT(customMenuRequested(QPoint)));
```